# Array empty in map returning promise - NODE JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

i am newbie on this.
My problem is when I tried to return array full of values, it returned empty.
I faced some weeks before and I solved it, declaring the map as a `const` and returning its value in a function... but I can't remeber how I did it.

This is my code:

```
module.exports.deleteLockedEmail = (req, res, next) => {
  const maxDateAd = new Date().getTime() - 2592000000;
  const adIdsToDelete = [];
  Admin.find({})
    .then(emailLocked => {
      const mapToLockedEm =  emailLocked.map(element => {
        return User.findOne({email:element.email})
                .then(userLocked => {
                  return adIdsToDelete.push(userLocked)
                })
                .catch(error => console.log(error))
      })
      return mapToLockedEm
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error))

  cron.schedule("* * * * *", function() {
  console.log("running a task every minute => delete locked ads");
  });
}
```

How can I fill this array?

```
adIdsToDelete = [];
```

Comment: Use `Promise.all`

Comment: i feel like this could be done a little cleaner by [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)

Comment: @AbdullahAbid I will try too, it is a good point of view

Answer (score 2):

Remember that all these calls to database are asynchronous. To get the values you have to wait till the promise is resolved and return values. In this case we can wait for all Promises with Promise.all to be executed and after that in next `then` context

```
module.exports.deleteLockedEmail = (req, res, next) => {
  const maxDateAd = new Date().getTime() - 2592000000;
  const adIdsToDelete = [];
  Admin.find({})
    .then(emailLocked => {
      const mapToLockedEm =  emailLocked.map(element => {
        return User.findOne({email:element.email})
                .then(userLocked => {
                  return adIdsToDelete.push(userLocked)
                })
                .catch(error => console.log(error))
      })
      return Promise.all(mapToLockedEm)
    }).then(() => {
      // In this context the adIdsToDelete will be filled
    });
    .catch(error => console.log(error))

  cron.schedule("* * * * *", function() {
  console.log("running a task every minute => delete locked ads");
  });
}
```

Also in general it can be a little tricky to work with variables like `adIdsToDelete` as they are in different scope than your promise chain. As it happened in your example - it can be confusing when this variable actually fills with values.

You can rewrite it as following

```
module.exports.deleteLockedEmail = (req, res, next) => {
  const maxDateAd = new Date().getTime() - 2592000000;
  Admin.find({})
    .then(emailLocked => {
      const mapToLockedEm =  emailLocked.map(element => {
        return User.findOne({email:element.email})
                .catch(error => console.log(error))
      })
      return Promise.all(mapToLockedEm)
    }).then(adIdsToDelete  => {
      // In this context the adIdsToDelete will be filled
    });
    .catch(error => console.log(error))

  cron.schedule("* * * * *", function() {
  console.log("running a task every minute => delete locked ads");
  });
}
```

Comment: You should avoid the `push`ing though, the `Promise.all` promise already resolves to an array of all results

Comment: @libik you are absolutely right! I apreciate very much your answer. I have a few question before I started to read more about promise all. 1. Need I write one more .catch? 2. I tried before I posted my question promise.all, but creating new varaible testPromise = , but it didn't work. Promise.all don't need to be promise, just have inside a varaible a promise? Again, thank you! Thank you all.

Comment: @Bergi, it did't work, could you be more specific? thanks!

Comment: @Bergi - yes, good point, I was actually also considering this path, but I wanted to keep it as simple as possible to address the core issue. However I edited it with one more option that reflects it.

Comment: @titoih - its enough to have just one `catch` at the end of the promise chain, then any error thrown in promise chain will bubble up to that `catch`. You should use other `catches` only when you dont want to break whole promise chain in case of error (like now, when `User.findOne` ends with error for any reason, it will be catched by internal catch and the promise chain will continue as nothing happens. If this is what you want, keep it. If you want to abort any processing in case of unexpected error, you should remove the internal catch

Comment: @titoih - not sure what you mean in your Promise.all question. Just imagine Promise.all as some breakpoint, that will wait for all the promises inside to finish before it continues. It does not affect how the promises inside are handled.

Comment: @libik finally, and thanks of you, I understand. I really apreciate it!! and by the way, it works :)